# Hibernate/Oracle/Spring: java.sql.SQLException: Protocol violation

Tags: oracle, spring, hibernate, maven, oracle10g

Can you please help me, when I try to execute update hql with Hibernate/Oracle 10.2 I got error below:

I'm using Java 1.6.

In my maven:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
<artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
<version>10.2.0.4.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
<version>1.0.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

The exception :

```
Caused by: org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not roll back JPA transaction;
Caused by: org.hibernate.TransactionException: rollback failed
Caused by: org.hibernate.TransactionException: unable to rollback against JDBC connection
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Protocol violation
```

Thanks.

Comment: show us the code that created the issue...

Comment: Have you seen any OutOfMemoryError exceptions prior to that?

Answer (score 0):

I've found solution.
I've changed my codes from, just removing the cascade attribute:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "scheduleRequest", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
public Set<AdhocDetail> getAdhocDetails() {
return this.adhocDetails;
}
```

to:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "scheduleRequest")
public Set<AdhocDetail> getAdhocDetails() {
return this.adhocDetails;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Hi ManuPK and Olaf. I'm trying to post reply for you but unable to submit when I click "Add Comment" button. Thanks though for your reply.